# Is it possible to drag a circle in a SVG using JQuery UI Dragable?

Tags: jquery-ui, svg

I have trouble dragging a circle in SVG using JQuery UI dragable. Please note that I just want to drag the circle in svg not the entire svg. Thank you guys this is not a homework so please give me some codes that make it work.I have searched hours on internet for a solution and found nothing helpful!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>svg</title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<svg width="800" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title></title>
    <desc></desc>
    <circle id="circle" cx="60" cy="60" r="60" style="fill: #ff9; stroke: red;">
    </circle>
</svg>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
$( function() {
        $("#circle").draggable();
    } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This should work, yet you may consider using the `<svg>` or `<div>` element to drag versus the circle path itself. Since you're essentially changing it's `top` and `left` inside the view port of the SVG element.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your exact code, you get this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#circle").draggable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <svg width="800" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title></title>
    <desc></desc>
    <circle id="circle" cx="60" cy="60" r="60" style="fill: #ff9; stroke: red;">
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Yes, you can drag the circle and move it, yet once you let go, it gets assigned a new `x,y` basically via styling. This will have varied results. Try dragging it just a small bit and see what happens.

If you wrap the SVG or you target that itself, you may get better results when dragging.

```js
$(function() {
  $("svg").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="svg-wrap" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
  <svg width="122" height="122" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title></title>
    <desc></desc>
    <circle id="circle" cx="60" cy="60" r="60" style="fill: #ff9; stroke: red;">
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

This allows you to move the circle as a SVG within the parent container.

Hope that helps.